# JPA superset using CriteriaQuery API

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Given the following classes:

```
@Entity
public class Recipe {

    @Id
    @Column
    private long id; 

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "recipe_ingredient", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
    private Set<String> ingredients;

    ...
}
```

How can I write the in JPA using the CriteriaQuery API the following: 
"Given a list of ingredients, return the Recipes that have at least all of the specified ingredients"

Comment: Sure you want the Criteria API?  It's deprecated: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria

Comment: corrected, looking for `javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery`

Comment: You can do a query with multiple "IN" clauses, one for each of the ingredients you want to check. That is true regardless of whether it is JPQL or Criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Offhand, it can be something like:

`criteria.add(Restrictions.in("recipe.ingredients", ingredients));`

where `ingredients` is a collection of ingredient strings.  Add an alias if `ingredients` throws you an exception.

Warning: Criteria API is now [deprecated](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria).

Otherwise, you can take a look [here for an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976422/how-to-query-a-property-of-type-liststringin-jpa)

Comment: `in` doesn't provide the result I'm looking for.  This would result in a recipe just because there was one ingredient match.  I only want recipes if all I've got all the ingredients.

Comment: Something like this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781010/hibernate-criteria-query-collections-contains-certain-elements

Comment: same general question - doesn't look like there's much of an answer there.

Comment: Perhaps the poster mean the JPA CriteriaQuery API ... since he mentioned JPA explicitly in the question. This most certainly is not deprecated (not that it is particularly nice either).

Comment: Yes, looking for JPA CriteriaQuery API.